# java http client for file upload to sharepoint using kerberos authentication

Tags: java, sharepoint, httpclient

Need standalone Java program that facilitate uploading files to Sharepoint using KERBEROS authentication.

We have sharepoint server which is upgraded to 2010 version and is configured with Kerberos authentication. Earlier sharepoint version was using NTLM authentication for which I have javaq client program to upload files from local system. Since sharepoint got upgraded with Kerberos authentication, I need to modify current NTLM versioned java program to use Kerberos. I got code snippet for authentication and connectivity which is working fine. I am able to read Sharepoint URL and download a specific file though java program. Now I am trying upload file to Sharepoint but not getting the required java classes and jar files to be used for this.

I had Kerberos configuration setup using SPNEGO API to connect sharepoint.

Conf files: 
krb5.conf 
login.conf

API used to Kerberos Auth: 
spnego-r7.jar

Connectivity: 
Following code I am using for connectivity and File download which is perfectly working.

```
spnego = new SpnegoHttpURLConnection("spnego-client", <<sharepoint_user>>, <<sharepoint_password>>); 

//New Lines added to omit SSL Handshake exception 
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{ 
new X509TrustManager() { 
public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){ 
return null; 
} 
public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certific ate[] certs, String authType){ 
//No need to implement. 
} 
public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certific ate[] certs, String authType){ 
//No need to implement. 
} 
} 
}; 
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom()); 
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.g etSocketFactory()); 
spnego.connect(new URL(spLocation)); 
System.out.println("spnego.getResponseCode():: "+spnego.getResponseCode()); 
if(spnego.getResponseCode() >= 200) { 
log.debug("Authentication Successful"); 
}
```

File Read/Download:

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream( spnego.getInputStream()); 
java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputFile); 
java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024); 
byte[] data = new byte[1024]; 
int x=0; 
System.out.println("4" + outputFile.length()); 
while((x=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0) { 
bout.write(data,0,x); 
} 
bout.close(); 
in.close();
```

could you advise how to upload files to Sharepoint folder using java code. I searched many forums for hours but not getting exact code for File upload. Your advice on this much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For NTLM authentication: There is PutMethod in webdev library (org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.client.methods.PutMethod) which I can pass to HttpClient (org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient) client.executeMethod(method); Now I am trying to use same classes in  Kerberos authentication. But I am unable to get org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient from upon kerberos authentication. can you please advise. -- Polireddy

Answer (score 0):

Finally after 10 days of research and search through many blogs, I got solution for my problem. I hope this helps someone needy:

UPLOAD MULTIPLE FILES TO SHAREPOINT (KERBEROS AUTHENTICated):

```
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", workareaFolder+"/"+props.getProperty("kerberos.conf.file"));
    System.setProperty( "java.security.auth.login.config", workareaFolder+"/"+props.getProperty("jass.conf.file"));
    System.setProperty( "javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");           

    krb5MechOid    = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
    spnegoMechOid  = new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.2");

      shost= targetSPN.toLowerCase();
      if (shost.startsWith("http/") || shost.startsWith("cifs/") )  {
          shost = shost.substring(5);
      }  
      else  {
          log.debug("Entered invalid SPN.  Must begin with HTTP/ or CIFS/");
          System.exit(-1);
      }
      this.checkSPNHostname(shost);                     

    //login to the KDC using JAAS login module
    this.subject = login(username, password);

    log.debug(this.subject);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                String authType) {
                }
    } }, new SecureRandom());

    Scheme httpScheme80 = new  Scheme("http", 80,  PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory());
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext,SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    Scheme httpsScheme = new  Scheme("https", 443, sf);

    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);
    schemeRegistry.register(httpScheme80);

    // Create Connection Manager instance for use by Httpclient
    cm = new SingleClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm,params);
    httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy());

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                                                public boolean accept(File f) {
                                                    if (f.isFile()) {
                                                        return true;
                                                    }
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            });
    String[] url = new String[listOfFiles.length];
    String spTargetFolder = new String();

    totalFilesInReportsFolder = listOfFiles.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < totalFilesInReportsFolder; i++) {
        uploadFileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        log.info("\nFile: "+uploadFileName);

        spTargetFolder = this.getSPFolder(uploadFileName);
        spDestinationFolderURL = sharedDocumentsRoot + instanceFolder + "/" + spTargetFolder + "/" + uploadFileName;
        //log.info("Destination URL : " + spDestinationFolderURL);

        httpPut = new HttpPut(new URI(sharedDocumentsRoot + instanceFolder + "/" + spTargetFolder + "/" + uploadFileName));
        httpPut.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",true);
        InputStreamEntity inputStreamEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(listOfFiles[i]), listOfFiles[i].length());
        httpPut.setEntity(inputStreamEntity);
        // Get the service ticket for targetSPN and set it in HttpPut Authorization header
        this.serviceTicket= initiateSecurityContext( targetSPN );
        encodedBytes  = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(this.serviceTicket);
        encoded =   new String(encodedBytes);
        httpPut.addHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate " + encoded);

        httpResponse = null;

        try {
             log.info("Uploading File... ");
             log.debug("Executing httpPut request: " + httpPut.getRequestLine());           
             httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
             log.debug("After Post - Status code:" +httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
             StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
             String sResponse; 
             while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 s = s.append(sResponse);
             }


             if (httpResponse.getStatusLine() != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                 log.info("Response Code received: "+ httpResponse.getStatusLine() +" [200 - CREATE / OVERWRITE]");
                 log.info("File Sucessfully uploaded to Sharepoint location: "+spDestinationFolderURL );
                 uploadSuccessCount++;
             } else {
                 log.error("Error while uploading file to sharepoint");
                 if (httpResponse.getStatusLine() != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_CREATED){
                     log.error("Response code: "+httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                     log.error("Response Text:" + s);
                 }
                 uploadFailCount++;
             }

             log.debug("----------------------------------------");
             log.debug("Response StatusLine: "+ httpResponse.getStatusLine());
             log.debug("----------------------------------------");
             log.debug("Return Code : " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
             log.debug("----------------------------------------");

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            log.error("Exception while uploading report \""+uploadFileName+"\" to Share point="+exp);
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```